# Movie background iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmoviewcontroller

I am trying create an application with movie background , I have a .mov video clip which i want put it on background and overlay with buttons  and .... what is the best way to do so ? does MPMovieController good idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use a MPMovieController.  Then remove the controls (play, pause).

```
moviecontroller.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

Then make it so that it repeats.

```
moviecontroller.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
```

Hope this helps!